# How to do a loop script in a widget with script?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do a loop in a widget, but the widget have a internal script:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body>

<script>
  list=["AMAR3","BBDC4", "BEEF3", "BPAN4", "BRFS3", "B3SA3", "CVCB3", "EVEN3", "IRBR3", "JBSS3","MGLU3", "MRFG3", "PETR4", "QUAL3", "RADL3", "USIM5", "VVAR3"]

  for(i in list){

    <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
      <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://br.tradingview.com/symbols/BMFBOVESPA-" + list[i] + "/technicals/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Análise Técnica de list[i]</span></a> por TradingView</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-technical-analysis.js" async>
      {
      "interval": "1m",
      "width": 425,
      "colorTheme": "light",
      "isTransparent": false,
      "height": 450,
      "symbol": "BMFBOVESPA" + list[i],
      "showIntervalTabs": true,
      "locale": "br"
    }
  </script>

</div>
  <!-- TradingView Widget END -->

</script></body></html>
```

In this situation the code don't display the widget. I want to create a personalized page with this widgets.
If you can help to understand why the error.

Comment: You are going to have to dynamically build the html

Comment: it doesn't look like valid HTML, you can't put HTML inside a <script> tag.

Comment: What the people above said. Also, do you really want to include that inner JavaScript 17 times? Surely there must be a better design, or so I would hope.

Answer (score 1):

You can write multiple lines inside:

```
``
```

Write your code in this way:

```js
list=["AMAR3","BBDC4", "BEEF3", "BPAN4", "BRFS3", "B3SA3", "CVCB3", "EVEN3", "IRBR3", "JBSS3","MGLU3", "MRFG3", "PETR4", "QUAL3", "RADL3", "USIM5", "VVAR3"];
for(i of list){
document.body.innerHTML += `

<div>
<h1>`+i+`</h1>
<div>

`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn all the html into strings, not sure about the tradingview script and if it is properly readying that little json snippet.  This script is just treating everything in the loop as 1 group - you may want to play with what is actually needed inside the loop.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body>

<script>
  var list = ["AMAR3","BBDC4", "BEEF3", "BPAN4", "BRFS3", "B3SA3", "CVCB3", "EVEN3", "IRBR3", "JBSS3","MGLU3", "MRFG3", "PETR4", "QUAL3", "RADL3", "USIM5", "VVAR3"];
  for(i in list){

    var _html = '<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->'+
    '<div class="tradingview-widget-container">'+
     '<div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>'+
    '<div class="tradingview-widget-copyright">'+
    '<a href="https://br.tradingview.com/symbols/BMFBOVESPA-" '+ list[i] +    '"/technicals/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">'+
    '<span class="blue-text">Análise Técnica de'+ list[i]+'</span>'+
    '</a> por TradingView</div>'+
    '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-technical-analysis.js" async> {"interval": "1m", "width": 425, "colorTheme": "light","isTransparent": false,"height": 450,"symbol": "BMFBOVESPA"' + list[i] + ',"showIntervalTabs": true, "locale":"br"}<//script>'+
'</div><!-- TradingView Widget END -->';
document.body.innerHTML +=_html;
}


</script></body></html>
```